# Can't get go exec command to execute git config command properly

Tags: git, go

I have am trying to execute a git command from a golang program to get the url of git's remote. Below is the code. It keeps throwing an "exit status 1" error.

```
func main() {
    var out bytes.Buffer
    var stderr bytes.Buffer
    cmd := exec.Command(`C:\3rdPartySoftware\Git\bin\git.exe`,[]string{"config","--get", "remote.origin.url"}...)
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &stderr
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + stderr.String())
      os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
}
```

OUTPUT:-

exit status 1:

Comment: $ git config --get remote.origin.url
> `code` https://<url of git project>

Comment: Is this program executed in the directory with a git repo?

Comment: @Lander : Yes it is...

Comment: ok I resolved the issue. I explicitly set the command dir to the git project using cmd.Dir

Comment: Are you sure? I just ran it (with this code on my Mac: http://play.golang.org/p/3w-AzDe5z3) and it worked fine. edit: glad to see you got it resolved

Comment: @Lander : Thanks...Your answer pointed me to the right direction.

Comment: @Konoha maybe you can answer your own question since you solved it? :)